# How to encode the url in Javascript

Tags: javascript, urlencode

How to encode the url in this case: http://jsfiddle.net/spem/c89r1vu1/4/

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$('#pnumbers li strong').each(function () {
    var html = $(this).html();
    $(this).html('<a href="http://example.com/search_query=' + html + '">' + html + '</a>');
});
</script>
<div id="pnumbers" class="rte">
    <ul>
        <li><strong>Isto é um teste</strong>

        </li>
        <li><strong>HP Q1292-67026</strong>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you're asking about the [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) function.

Comment: Yes just do not know how to apply. I do not understand programming. Can exemplify how?

Comment: so when you add `html` into your string, just wrap it in `encodeURIComponent()`. So it will look like this: `encodeURIComponent(html)`.